# EF query with dynamic properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am trying to refractor an old .Net Core MVC codeset with repetitive loops of if/else's, to construct EF IQueryable, with the below dynamic expresssion.

```
   foreach (var propertyInfo in properties)
   {
       if (key == propertyInfo.Name.ToLower())
           q = q.Where(ct => 
              ct.GetType().GetProperty(propertyInfo.Name)
                  .GetValue(ct, null).ToString().Contains(val));
   }
```

However, I receive below error. Any idea how to make this codeset work

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet<>.Where(v => v.GetType().GetProperty(__propertyInfo_Name_0).GetValue' could not be translated. Either rewrite
> the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client
> evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(),
> AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). "

Comment: In the loop try attaching a `.ToList()` or `AsEnumerable()` to `properties`. Also where is the `OrderByDescending()`

Comment: What type is `properties`, is it a `IEnumerable<PropertyInfo>` (i.e., from Reflection)?  What type is `q`?  And `key`?  I don't see any *order-by-ness* in your code, nor do I see a `DbSet`.  What are we looking at?

Comment: Are you trying to build an `Expression` that you can apply to a `DbSet` or an `IQueryable`?  Have you looked at *Predicate Builder*? http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Comment: @janzen the properties.ToLIst() produce same error.

Comment: @Flydog57 this is just a snipper of a  longer IQuerable q . The properties is PropertyInfo[]